# OpenSTLinux - how to add sources to apt-get?

Tags: linux, apt, arm

I am using openSTLinux with kernel version 4.19 on the STM32MP157c-dk2 board. It turns out a lot of software I need isn't installed by default and I need to show a proof of concept project working.

`apt-get` is installed. However `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` doesn't have any files in it. I'm not sure what to even add.

`lsb_release -s -i` returns: **openstlinux-western**

`uname -m` returns: **armv7l**

When I try to run `apt-get install git` git can't be found, as is the case with anything else I want to install.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information of how to use this site. To get to your question, is the device you are using [this?](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-discovery-kits/stm32mp157c-dk2.html#overview) I was able to find a [wiki](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Main_Page) what have you found in the documentation about installing software?

Comment: When you decided to get this device, were you provided any information about supported software, or how to update and otherwise manage this device?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** As of June 9th 2020, ST has created a Package repository for the OpenSTLinux distribution. So if you are using the [Starter Package](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/STM32MP1Starter.html) for the STM32MP157C-DK2 board, you can use apt-get. More information at [Package repository for OpenSTLinux distribution](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Package_repository_for_OpenSTLinux_distribution).

I have had the same problem, and for a while I could not find any useful information on the matter until I came across the question [How to install additional software on STM32MP157C-DK2 from internet](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BzvLmdSQE/how-to-install-additional-software-on-stm32mp157cdk2-from-internet) on the ST Community.

To use apt-get, there has to be a Package repository maintained by a person or group of people, who is packaging the programs and applications to that particular Linux distribution.

And, since there is no `sources.list` file at `/etc/apt/` in the openstlinux-western distribution that comes with the STM32MP157C-DK2 board, we can not use this method to install programs.

Take a look at the [How to integrate an external software package](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_integrate_an_external_software_package) article from ST wiki page.